# numpy function with float or ndarray as argument

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

Consider the following code.

```
import numpy as np

def f(x, y):
    return (x[:, np.newaxis] - y[:]).sum(axis = 1)

x1 = np.linspace(1, 2, 5)
y1 = np.linspace(3, 4, 7)

print(f(x1, y1))

# x2 = 2. # (won't work)
# x2 = [2.] # (won't work either)
x2 = np.asarray([2.])
print(f(x2, y1))

# x3, _ = np.meshgrid(x1, x1) # won't work
# print(f(x3, y1))
```

The first call `f(x1, y1)` works as expected.

The second call, the float needs to be "converted" before it works (I'd like the conversion to be transparent for users, so the conversion should be included in the definition of the function).

The third call does not work at all and I don't know how to tune the definition of the function so that it does the same as the first call but for some points on a grid.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the problem of transparent conversion of floats, at least, you could use the [`np.atleast_1d()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_1d.html) method inside your definition:

```
def f(x, y):
    x_ = np.atleast_1d(x)
    y_ = np.atleast_1d(y)
    return (x_[:, np.newaxis] - y_[:]).sum(axis = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks (+1). Good to know about that method.

Comment: Sorry about the typo. I take it from your edit that you don't want to ensure ``y`` is also at least a 1d array?

Comment: Ok, it might answer the question for others though. Would probably be incomplete otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the subtraction along the other axis and force `x` to be an array of a compatible dimension:

```
import numpy as np

def g(x,y):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    if len(x.shape)==2:
        return (x - y[:,np.newaxis, np.newaxis]).sum(axis=0)
    return (x - y[:,np.newaxis]).sum(axis=0)

x1 = np.linspace(1, 2, 5)
y1 = np.linspace(3, 4, 7)

print('x1 =', x1)
print('y1 =', y1)
print('g(x1,y1) =', g(x1, y1))

x2 = 2.
print('x2 =', x2)
print('y1 =', y1)
print('g(x2, y1) =', g(x2, y1))

x3, _ = np.meshgrid(x1, x1)

print('x3 =', x3)
print('g(x3,y1) =', g(x3, y1))
```

Output:

```
x1 = [ 1.    1.25  1.5   1.75  2.  ]
y1 = [ 3.          3.16666667  3.33333333  3.5         3.66666667  3.83333333
  4.        ]
g(x1,y1) = [-17.5  -15.75 -14.   -12.25 -10.5 ]
x2 = 2.0
y1 = [ 3.          3.16666667  3.33333333  3.5         3.66666667  3.83333333
  4.        ]
g(x2, y1) = [-10.5]
x3 = [[ 1.    1.25  1.5   1.75  2.  ]
 [ 1.    1.25  1.5   1.75  2.  ]
 [ 1.    1.25  1.5   1.75  2.  ]
 [ 1.    1.25  1.5   1.75  2.  ]
 [ 1.    1.25  1.5   1.75  2.  ]]
g(x3,y1) = [[-17.5  -15.75 -14.   -12.25 -10.5 ]
 [-17.5  -15.75 -14.   -12.25 -10.5 ]
 [-17.5  -15.75 -14.   -12.25 -10.5 ]
 [-17.5  -15.75 -14.   -12.25 -10.5 ]
 [-17.5  -15.75 -14.   -12.25 -10.5 ]]
```

Comment: Thanks (+1). It works. I was hoping not to have to do some `if else` but if there is no other options.